# Reverse a string containing ASCII chars and non-ASCII chars

Tags: c, string, non-ascii-characters

I got a problem about how to reverse a string containing this 'abcd汉字efg'.

```
str_to_reverse = "abcd汉字efg"; /* those non-ASCII chars are Chinese characters, each of them takes 2 bytes */
```

after reversion, it should be:

```
str_toreverse = "gfe字汉dcba";
```

I thought, to reverse the string, I gotta identify those non-ASCII chars, because I think that simply reversing every byte won't get the right answer.

How can I do it?

PS:
I wrote this program under Ubuntu, 32-bit.
then I printed every byte:

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    printf("%c", s[i]);
```

I got some gibberish text instead of "汉字".

Comment: You shouldn't have to identify the non-ASCII chars, the string should either have 16 bit chars or 8 bit chars, I don't think you can mix and match. Your normal ASCII chars in that string are actually 16 bit chars.

Comment: What platform? VisualC(++)/gcc/ANSI C?

Comment: @Kratz There is a marvellous world out of here...a world full of MBCS and UTF-8 :-)

Comment: @Kratz, if it is UTF-8, then yes you can.

Comment: @xanatos, Really? You learn something everyday.

Comment: @Kratz Trust me, you don't want to learn about MBCS :-)

Comment: I've never understood what people need to reverse strings for, except as easy-to-explain exercises in introductory programming courses. Anyway, how ambitious are you? Is it enough to reverse the order of Unicode codepoints, or do you also need to preserve which characters any combining accents in the string attach to?

Comment: It's becoming a competition... What about RTL mark and LTR mark special characters? :-)

Comment: @Alcott They are "hints" about the direction of text used for showing the text. And they are RTL Marks (Right to Left Mark) and LTR Mark. Read for example here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark I'll add that there are many other "special" characters (read here http://unicode.org/reports/tr9/#Explicit_Directional_Overrides ) that shouldn't be reversed if you want to reverse "correctly". Plus everything Henning wrote. They can even be used in a stack-like fashion (using PDF to pop :-) )

Comment: @xanatos, thanks, but how to use RTL or LTR to solve my problem?

Comment: @Alcott No no... They could be PART of your problem. If you reverse `abc` you get `cba` and you can show correctly `cba`, but if you reverse something like `<RLM>abc<PDF>` (where RLM is Right to left Mark and PDF is the POP) you'll get `<PDF>cba<RLM>`. You are popping before pushing :-)

Comment: @Alcott So that you can appreciate the complexity of correctly solving your problem, the ICU library (one of the best free C/C++ libraries for handling UNICODE) has equivalent for many C string functions BUT NOT for strrev :-) (http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ustring_8h.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pure C89 answer:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char const* str;
    size_t slen;
    char* rev;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    str = "abcd汉字efg";
    printf("%s\n", str);
    slen = strlen(str);
    rev = malloc(slen+1)+slen;
    *--rev = '\0';
    while (*str != '\0') {
        int clen, i;
        clen = mblen(str, slen);
        if (clen == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Bad encoding\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < clen; ++i) {
            *--rev = str[clen-1-i];
        }
        str += clen;
    }
    printf("%s\n", rev);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, it works. BTW, am I supposed to set locale back at the end of the program?

Answer (score 3):

If the string is encoded as utf8, it is pretty simple. You can obtain the length of *well formed* utf8 sequences by inspecting only the first byte.

In a first pass you reverse *only* the utf8 "subsequences" (those with length > 1)
In a second pass you reverse the whole string.
Voila.

Comment: +1 for a clever but simple solution. It's not optimal (2 passes) but it's easy to implement and to see that it's correct.

Comment: @wildplasser, I just wrote the program under Ubuntu's gnome-terminal through vim, I re-edited my post, and the output I added contains some gibberish text instead of the non-ASCII chars.

Comment: well, maybe it is not encoded in utf8. Remeber, it is *your* string ;-]

Comment: Also: for (i=0; i < strlen(s); i++) {} is considered bad idiom. It might result in strlen() being called on every iteration, leading to O(N*N) behavior.